# Integrating locally installed PingFederate with Facebook

Tags: facebook, pingfederate

We have installed PingFederate 7.1 in our local desktop (not in cloud). Now want to integrate with facebook. Is it possible?
We tried with documents available for integrating facebook with cloud enabled pingfederate. But it is not working.
Can anybody pls help here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. It works in local installations also. Just to put the port number for your facebook endpoints.